# Why $x^2$ may not be a solution to a general second order homogenous differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm relatively new to differential equations and I recently read that if the functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are continuous at $x=0$ then it is never possible for $x^2$ to be a solution to the equation $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y = 0$

Given that this is still relatively elementary work as I've only just started looking at second order differential equations, I was wondering if anyone could explain this to me please as I can't see how it holds with the theorems I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** Substituting $x^2$ into the equation $$y'' + p(x) y' + q(x) y$$ gives that $$(2) + p(x) (2x) + q(x) (x^2) = 0.$$
Now, what happens at $x = 0$?

Comment: Ah, ok. I was expecting something a little more theorem based than this by the way the book talks but this makes complete sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found it useful. Since $x^2$ is a specific function, in this case it's easiest simply to substitute. Note that we only used a particular property of $x^2$ and so our argument proves a more general result: A general second-order linear ODE $y'' + py' + qy = 0$ with coefficient functions continuous at $x = x_0$ has no solution that vanishes precisely to second order at $x = x_0$. In fact, the same sort of argument shows that this still holds if we replace second order with $k$th order in both uses of the term.

Answer (score 2):

Subsititute $y=x^2$ in $y''+p(x)y'+q(x)y$ and you'll get

$$2+2p(x)x+q(x)x^2$$

Now, what is the limit of this for $x\to 0$ assuming continuity of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$?

Comment: We only need $p$ and $q$ to be *defined* at $x=0$.